# How to have a PHP variable with HTML wrapped inside of JavaScript with both single quotes and double quotes already used

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to have a PHP variable with HTML wrapped inside of JavaScript with both single quotes and double quotes already used.  I've tried escaping them, but it is just breaking it.

```
$html_php = "
'<div class=\"release-timer-div\" id=\"days\">Next Release <span class=\"release-timer-span\">.</span></div><div class=\"release-timer-div\" id=\"days\">' + days + '<span class=\"release-timer-span\">days</span></div><div class=\"release-timer-div\" id=\"hours\">' + hours + '<span class=\"release-timer-span\">hrs</span></div><div class=\"release-timer-div\" id=\"minutes\">' + minutes + '<span class=\"release-timer-span\">min</span></div><div class=\"release-timer-div\" id=\"seconds\">' + seconds + '<span class=\"release-timer-span\">sec</span></div>'
";
```

Comment: have u tried using PHP heredoc?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Are [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) ( ` ) possible in your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

you can't combine like that,  i recomend you to use pure php script in code bellow using "." and $(variable) to combine text , and using js after hole html is render on page so you can manipulate using id of element or class name.

```
 $var = '<div class="release-timer-div" id="days">Next Release <span class="release-timer-span">.</span></div><div class="release-timer-div" id="days">'.$day.'<span class="release-timer-span">days</span></div><div class="release-timer-div" id="hours">'.$hour.'<span class="release-timer-span">hrs</span></div><div class="release-timer-div" id="minutes">'.$minutes.'<span class="release-timer-span">min</span></div><div class="release-timer-div" id="seconds">'.$seconds.'<span class="release-timer-span">sec</span></div>';
```

if you're using api call, just using js for render the page. dont combine between 2 language it too complicated. 
hope this answer your question.